# Update com caractere no meio da string

Tags: mysql

Tenho milhares de registros com um código num formato bem peculiar que identifica caixas em postes na rua.

Ex.: 21.305-005/100-A

Porém atualmente esse código se encontra no formato 21305005100-A. Como a posição da pontuação é fixa, padrão de CEP, estou tentando coloca-los porém desconheço qualquer função que faça isso.

Sei que poderia fazer isso com relativa facilidade em php, mas gostaria de aprender direto em um update no mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ideal é armazenar somente o código e deixar a formatação para o frontend, por questões de desempenho e modelagem.

Para realizar essa operação, você pode utilizar a combinação das funções `concat` e `substr` ou `substring` conforme abaixo:

```
UPDATE teste
SET numeros = CONCAT(SUBSTR(numeros,1,2), '.',SUBSTR(numeros,3,3),'-',SUBSTR(numeros,6,3),'/',SUBSTR(numeros,9,5));
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Comment: Assim deu, porem acho que é substring(...)

Comment: Na documentação indica as duas opções como válidas, vou editar ali na resposta e incluir os links para ficar mais completo :)

Answer (score 1):

Antes de fazer um `update` diretamente gosto de fazer um `select` para verificar como ira ficar o resultado do `update`, assim, fiz um teste no [SQLTest](http://sqltest.net/).

```
CREATE TABLE poste ( 
numero VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO poste
VALUES
  ('21305005100-A');
```

E a consulta:

```
select concat(substr(numero,1,2),'.',
              substr(numero,3,3),'-',
              substr(numero,6,3),'/',
              substr(numero,9,5))
  from poste;
```

Tendo o resultado esperado, então faço o `update`:

```
UPDATE poste
SET numero = concat(substr(numero,1,2),'.',
              substr(numero,3,3),'-',
              substr(numero,6,3),'/',
              substr(numero,9,5))
```